# Arrange 1-n^2 in n×n grid satisfy products of rows equal to products columns

Tags: performance-tuning, combinatorics, permutation

For which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is it possible to arrange $\{1,…,n^2\}$ in an $n\times n$ grid so that the set of products of columns equals the set of products of rows?

I can find solution for $3\times 3$ using brute method but unable to generalize for  $n\times n$.

```
MatrixForm@Partition[#, 3] & /@ 
 Cases[Permutations[Range[9]], {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_} /;
   {a b c, d e f, g h i} == {a d g, b e h, c f i}]
```

$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 & 1 & 6 \\
 2 & 7 & 4 \\
 3 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$  ......

Is it possible to use Mathematica to find instances for larger n in a smarter way? Don't have to find all solutions, of course, more is better.

Comment: I think in order to solve this you should think of sums of vectors of prime powers of elements on each row and column. I suspect that one can prove manually that solutions don't exist for certain dimensions of the matrix easier than actually formulate the question in to Mathematica...

Comment: Prime powers in integer factorisations, that is. After all they're unique, and effectively equal products correspond with equal sums of powers on prime factorisations...

Comment: Related link: [can-we-arrange-1-16-in-4-times-4-grid-so-products-of-rows-produ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518460/can-we-arrange-1-16-in-4-times-4-grid-so-products-of-rows-produ)

Answer (score 3):

The brute-force method you used works great for $n=3$ but there are too many permutations for values of $n$ greater than 3. Because you've stated that you don't necessarily need all solutions, another brute-force approach might do (at least for $n=4$).  (And I'm sure this can be made more efficient.)

```
n = 4;
m = Range[n^2];
nsim = 10000000;
count = 0;
Do[
 k = ArrayReshape[RandomSample[m, n^2], {n, n}];
 If[(Times @@ # & /@ k // Sort) == (Times @@ # & /@ Transpose[k] // Sort), 
   Print[k]; count = count + 1],
 {i, nsim}]
proportion = count/nsim // N
```

Running this a few times I've found the following solutions for $n=4$:

```
m1 = {{6, 14, 2, 12}, {8, 10, 9, 13}, {5, 11, 7, 4}, {3, 1, 16, 15}};
m2 = {{14, 2, 10, 3}, {5, 13, 12, 4}, {16, 15, 7, 6}, {9, 8, 1, 11}};
m3 = {{9, 5, 14, 13}, {11, 3, 2, 15}, {10, 12, 4, 6}, {1, 16, 8, 7}};
m4 = {{16, 9, 13, 2}, {10, 4, 8, 15}, {6, 11, 12, 7}, {5, 14, 3, 1}};
m5 = {{16, 9, 2, 11}, {1, 10, 6, 12}, {5, 7, 4, 8}, {14, 13, 15, 3}};
m6 = {{2, 13, 12, 14}, {5, 8, 16, 3}, {4, 6, 1, 15}, {9, 7, 10, 11}};
m7 = {{1, 10, 13, 12}, {16, 6, 4, 3}, {9, 14, 2, 5}, {8, 11, 15, 7}};
m8 = {{13, 15, 2, 14}, {7, 8, 12, 11}, {6, 9, 5, 16}, {10, 4, 1, 3}};
m9 = {{4, 3, 10, 11}, {9, 13, 7, 8}, {5, 12, 6, 1}, {2, 14, 16, 15}};
```

One could also use the random-permutations approach to estimate the number of solutions.  But that's more of a statistical question best addressed at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Mathematics StackExchange](https://match.stackexchange.com).